# using # in php variable

Tags: php, html, variables

[image]I have HTML entity #rn:url_param_value:i_id# this is a rightnow entity which fetches url parameters returns a value. I want to use the returned value as PHP variable. That entity will fetch the ID from the URL.
Eg

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/answer/a_id/#rn:url_param_value:a_id#"/>Answer</a>
```

here it will print the answer ID in the url.
I wnat to use that entity value in PHP variable like $_GET['ID']

```
<?php 

$id = "#rn:url_param_value:i_id#";

?>
```

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I have tried many ways to display its value in PHP but it wont display its value. This is just a starting point. I want to use this  ID in creating REST API

Comment: In that case, edit your question to add what you have tried and why they don't work.